Generate a Presigned S3 URL via AWS CLI (specifically for file UPLOAD)
Is it true you need to specify somehow put_object and method PUT when creating a presign URL.
The official docs say you have to, but CLI doesn't support it
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html

Correct, the CLI does not support put_object.  You'll need to use the SDK with some language like Python.

This question is similar to: Generating a presigned URL to upload to an S3 bucket. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If anyone is asking the sane question - you can't do generate presign URL for upload via CLI.
Create a Python script file with boto3. Use the official AWS S3 docs

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
